# Laravel 5 GenericDAO like Java + Hibernate

Tags: php, interface, laravel-5.4, eloquent

As I mentioned in the title, I want to achieve something similar or the best approach to GenericDAO in Laravel 5.4.

I've been working with Java and Hibernate for a while and I used to declare a generic interface with a generic implementation, specific interfaces that extends generic interface and specific implementations for those interfaces. This way, code keeps clear for a CRUD and I have to modify only the generic one, if I need to change a CRUD method. Also, I could change a specific method if I need to check or do some other things in that method.

In Java I used things like this:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, ID> extends Serializable {
    ...
}

public class GenericDAOImplHibernate<T, ID> extends Serializable implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {
    ...
}

public interface UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User, Integer> {
    ...
}

public class UserDAOImplHibernate extends GenericDAOImplHibernate<User, Integer> implements UserDAO {
    ...
}
```

And so on... I don't remember if it was exactly that, but something really similar. I hope you can help me with this kind of structure for a future project.

Thanks for your time.

Best regards,
Daglimioux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is first. I don't know if you knew, but PHP lacks of generics. There are some workarounds that emulate generics, but it gets tricky and I'd rather not go into that topic, when talking in regards to PHP. That being said, Laravel ships with an ORM called Eloquent, with the base model being `Model` (visit [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) to learn more) for any "Models" that you need to work with. Usually a model is paired with a [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations), in case you need your data stored in a database.

You get nice things out-of-the-box like all CRUD operations like: `$object->save()`, `$object->update(['attr'=>'value'])`, etc. Therefore, you barely have to implement these things on your own. You may extend `Model` and customize to your needs, if you want to override any of the implementations.

Again, since Laravel doesn't have any of the generic fanciness, the Model relationships and their implementations tend to be pretty linear. However, that doesn't prevent you from doing your regular interfaces and SOLID, many-to-many, one-to-one, etc.. stuff.

If you are new to Laravel, I recommend reading the docs and watching [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm new to Laravel, but I already read the documentation and I'm working in a project with Laravel. What I'm trying now is to create a Generic resource controller for eloquent, or something similar, then the rest will extend from that one and modify only which needs a specific method content. I prefer to ask this before we use a different project structure to find out what we can or we can not do. Again, thanks.

Comment: No worries, I am glad my answer helped you! One question... what made you switch from the well-known Spring+Hibernate environment to Laravel? Of course, if you dont mind me asking...

Comment: I was a big fan of Java, but I wasn't seeing a good progress in newer Java versions (1.7, 1.8...) related to hardware consumption, even for web. When I joined to the company where I'm working on, they had a great project (but developed probably by 3 monkeys, because it's impossible that a human-being could develop a project like that bad) and they used Symfony as framework. Recently, I had to start a development for a specific customer and I've been searching for something better than Symfony (which is great by its own) and I've found Laravel, that is based on Symfony but easier :)

Comment: Nice! Definitely Laravel is easier in my opinion. Not as fancy as Java though. What are your thoughts on Play Framework? Ever used it?

Comment: No, I never used it. Add me on Twitter (@Daglimioux) so we can discuss this further and any other questions :)